# Lower bound for a counting function of products of primes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $P$ be a non-empty finite set of prime numbers, and let $S(P)$ be such that $(\rm i)$ $P \subset S(P)$ and $(\rm ii)$ $p q \in S(P)$ for every $p, q \in S(P)$. Hence, $S(P)$ is the set of all products whose factors are (possibly repeated) members of $P$. In addition, let $S(P; N) = \{ x \in S \mid x \leq N \}$ for some integer $N > 2$. Is there a good non-trivial lower bound on $|S(P; N)|$? That is, in terms of $N$ and of some (hopefully, not all) of the elements of $P$.

The best I could find was $L(P, N) = 1 + \sum_{p \in P} \lfloor \log_p N \rfloor$, but I feel it is still lower than what's possible. If $P = \{ p \}$ for some prime $p$, then clearly $L(P, N) = |S(P; N)|$ since $S(P; N)$ is just the set of powers of $p$ that are $\leq N$, but otherwise it seems $L(P, N)$ is much lower than $|S(P; N)|$. For instance, if $P = \{ 2, 3 \}$ and $N = 10^6$, then $L(P, N) = 31$ while $|S(P; N)| = 142$.

Comment: Are we keeping $P$ fixed and letting $N$ to go infinity? If so, there is an asymptotic formula for the counting function. One can also extend the given lower bound to $1+\sum_{p\in P} \lfloor \log_p N\rfloor+\sum_{p_1<p_2\in P} \lfloor \log_{p_1p_2} N\rfloor$ and so on. There are also recursive formulas like $S(P,N) = S(P,N/p) + S(P\setminus\{p\},N)$ for any $p\in P$.

Comment: I think you may want to take a look to [smooth numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20an%20n,13%20are%20not%207%2Dsmooth.) and for $P=\{2,3\}$ [OEIS A071521](https://oeis.org/A071521) where you can find an asymptotic formula.

Comment: Thank you @FabiusWiesner for the reference.

Comment: @GregMartin, could you give me a reference to the asymptotic and recursive formulas?  I didn't manage to find much when looking for anything about this problem on my own.